# Print Survey Result template in pdf(v16)

Tags: templates, pdf, odoo, survey, odoo-16

I want to print survey results(/survey/results/survey_name) in PDF format on button click. I unable to putting exact code for this requirement.

if anybody can give me code for this then its helpful for me.

Thanks in advance
[image]